# Is the second derivative test for the concavity of variance inconclusive?

Tags: convex-analysis

For example, we know that

$var(x) = \sum\limits_i^n (p_ia_i)^2 - (\sum\limits_i^n (p_ia_i))^2$

Then

$\dfrac{\partial Var(x)}{\partial p_k} = \sum\limits_i^n (2p_ia_i) a_k - 2\sum\limits_i^n (p_ia_i)a_k = 0$

But we know that Variance is a concave function. Did I do something wrong in taking the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that 
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\operatorname{Var}(x)}{\partial p_k}
&=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}(p_ia_i)^2-\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}\left(\sum_ip_ia_i\right)^2 \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}(p_ka_k)^2-\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}\left(\sum_ip_ia_i\right)^2 \\
&= 2a_k^2-2a_k\sum_ip_ia_i\end{align}$$

Comment: Hmm there is something wrong with your last line, it should be $2p_ka_k^2 - 2a_k \sum_ip_ia_i$, but if you take the second derivative of that the whole thing becomes 0 so it is inconclusive